# How to use multiple RewriteCond in my htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I had this contents in my `.htaccess` file to handle my routing:

```
DirectoryIndex root.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . root.php [L]
```

Then I wanted to redirect users to my domain with leading "www." with this code I found on SO:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

So I removed the `L` flag from this condition and copied that code in there, so that this is my `.htaccess` file now:

```
DirectoryIndex root.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . root.php [L]
```

Unfortunately this leads to an Internal Server Error. How can I fix it and make both conditions work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex root.php    
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^root\.php$ root.php [L,NC]
```